# Slack bot: How to post a message on behalf of the user like the Giphy integration

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Like the image below, the Giphy integration is capable of posting a message on behalf of the user when receiving a `/gihpy` command **even though it does not require an OAuth flow.**

How can this app possibly have the user write a message without the user's token? I've searched the whole documentation but couldn't find the solution.

[image]

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [slash commands](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands)?

Comment: Also see [Sending messages as other entities](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#authorship)

Comment: I have both. "Slash commands" does not mention how to post as the user, and "Sending messages as other entities"'s approach is to simply change the name and icon (pretending to be the user) but still the composer is the bot. In Giphy's case, however, the user can edit or delete the auto-posted message, meaning that this message is considered to have been sent by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that without using the OAuth flow.

The apps like Giphy and Google Calendar are created by Slack's vendor partners, and hence they have features that normal custom apps does not have.

(e.g. Google calendar's modal UI is not available for normal custom apps)

Comment: Geekbot, a slack app is also able to post as me although I as a normal user did not allow my access token to it. Then how it is able to post as me?